# How do you put a DoubleClick ad on a WIX web site?

Tags: google-dfp

I'm trying to put a DoubleClick advertisement on a WIX web site.  From everything I have read, this seems to require putting a Google code snippet in the `<head/>` section of a web page.  However, it also seems WIX does not allow modifying the `<head/>` section of a page.

I want to believe one of the leading web site builders must support the leading advertising server, so I am thinking there must be a work around here.  Has anyone succeeded in getting this working?  Would the DFP API help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIX does not allow you to insert third party code into your website - this means there is absolutely no way to get DFP working on your page correctly.

You will need to use a better product to build your website.